# Set binding to null using ReactiveUI Bind method when ViewModel is set to null

Tags: c#, .net, reactiveui

I have a UserControl, which displays an item currently selected in a ListBox. SelectedItem of the ListBox is bound to the ViewModel property of the UserControl, which implements IViewFor interface. The ViewModel property is bound to DataContext of the control.

When I configure the bindings inside UserControl using code, the bindings are not updated whenever ViewModel is set to null (when no item is selected). If I use XAML instead, bindings become null whenever the context becomes null.

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior using Bind method in view constructor?

Here are the TicketsView.xaml.cs bindings:

```
// Tickets to TicketsListBox.ItemsSource

this
    .OneWayBind(ViewModel,
        vm => vm.Tickets,
        v => v.TicketsListBox.ItemsSource)
    .AddTo(disposables);

// CurrentTicket to TicketsListBox.SelectedItem

this
    .Bind(ViewModel,
        vm => vm.CurrentTicket,
        v => v.TicketsListBox.SelectedItem)
    .AddTo(disposables);

// CurrentTicket to TicketView.ViewModel

this
    .Bind(ViewModel,
        vm => vm.CurrentTicket,
        v => v.TicketView.ViewModel)
    .AddTo(disposables);
```

Here are the TicketView.xaml.cs bindings:

```
this
    .WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel)
    .BindTo(this, v => v.DataContext)
    .AddTo(disposables);

this
    .OneWayBind(ViewModel,
        vm => vm.Author,
        v => v.Label.Content)
    .AddTo(disposables);
```

Whenever ViewModel is set to null bindings do not update. XAML works as expected:

```
<UserControl ...>
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="Label" Content="{Binding Author}" />
</Grid>
```

Any way to achieve the same using code?

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How about this replacing your // CurrentTicket to TicketView.ViewModel

```
this.ViewModel
.WhenAnyValue (vm => vm.CurrentTicket,  
(vm) => vm == null ? null : vm
).BindTo (this.ViewModel, v => v.TicketView.ViewModel);
```

It will make your null binding in TicketView.xaml.cs work.